# Python Memory Profiler results different from expected

Tags: python

I am trying to get an understanding of using memory_profiler on my python app.
referring to the [Python memory profile guide](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) I copied the following code snippet :-

```
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def my_func():
a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
del b
return a
```

The expected result according to the link is :-

```
Line #    Mem usage  Increment   Line Contents
==============================================
 3                           @profile
 4      5.97 MB    0.00 MB   def my_func():
 5     13.61 MB    7.64 MB       a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
 6    166.20 MB  152.59 MB       b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
 7     13.61 MB -152.59 MB       del b
 8     13.61 MB    0.00 MB       return a
```

But when i ran my it on my VM running Ubuntu 16.04 I got the following results instead :-

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
 3     35.4 MiB     35.4 MiB   @profile
 4                             def my_func():
 5     43.0 MiB      7.7 MiB       a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
 6    195.7 MiB    152.6 MiB       b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
 7     43.1 MiB   -152.5 MiB       del b
 8     43.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       return a
```

There seems to be a huge overhead of around 30MiB difference between the expected and my run. I am trying to get an understanding of where this comes from and if I am doing anything incorrect. Should I be worried about it?

Please advice if anyone have any idea. Thanks

EDIT:

O/S : Ubuntu 16.06.4 (Xenial) running inside a VM

Python : Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.

Comment: The concrete result depends on your machine, hardware and os. You could not hope the numbers are all same on different machines.

Comment: can you edit your post to show the python version you're using?

Answer (score 0):

The memory taken by a list, or an integer heavily depends on the python version/build.

For instance, in python 3, all integers are long integers, whereas in python 2, long is used only when the integer doesn't fit in a CPU register / C `int`.

On my machine, python 2:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(2)
24
```

Python 3.6.2:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(2)
28
```

When computing your ratios vs the 24/28 ratio, it's pretty close:

```
>>> 195.7/166.2
1.177496991576414
>>> 28/24
1.1666666666666667
```

(this is probably not the only difference, but that's the most obvious I can think of)

So no, as long as the results are proportional, you shouldn't worry, but if you have memory issues with python integers (python 3, that is), you could use alternatives, like `numpy` or other native integer types.

Comment: I am not so much worried about the memory taken by integer or other types. I'm wondering more on the 30 over MiB taken up just running the application. To test this I wrote a simple Hello World python and profiled that and the result is consistent in that it still takes up around 30MiB which is quite big for something that only prints Hello World?